How to fix a bottom bracket shell that has been cut from outside?
I have a 27.5" MTB which has a damaged bottom bracket shell. When I install the bottom bracket into the shell, it does not stay in the center of the shell. It leans towards the bottom of the shell, almost touching it. I thought this problem was caused by the BB shell threads were damaged, though they looked OK to me. I took the bike to my LBS, they tried to fix it with a handmade tapping tool but it didn't work. Then I sent the frame of the bike to another bike shop in another city which claimed they can fix it. Frame came back , I rebuilt the bike and noticed the pedals were not turning smoothly and it started to creak after a short ride. I removed the BB again and see nothing was fixed, only the BB was renewed. Also noticed another thing; they shaved the outside of the BB shell on the drive side (that side had some damage when I bought the bike). Problem is they shaved it too deep and took the beginning of the threads as well. Now I think maybe the threads were ok but only the beginning of the threads were damaged because of the crush outside the shell and they tried to fix it by shaving it but failed. What do you think I can do at this point? Is there a way to fix it?



It's not impossible the frame was made out-of-spec at the factory. Has the bottom bracket always been problematic with this bike? Have you had the bike a long time?

I bought the bike second hand and it was already damaged on the outside edge of the BB shell.

Is the crank axle known to be true?

Yes. I bought myself two different bottom brackets and also the bike shop I sent the bike to installed a new BB. They were all square taper BB's. I had also a hollowtech BB and it was the same.

Are you attached to this frame?   It might be better to find a substitute rather than throwing more money at this one.   Sorry, sometimes money wins.

There are threadless bottom bracket repair kits available for just this problem. Without more details I don't know if one is available to match your drive train. It does not have external threads that screw into the frame. The left and right sides screw together and clamp to the outer edges of the frame.

Unfortunately they are not available in our country. Also they are for 68 mm shell width. Mine is 73 mm. I think they would still do the job though with some shifting issues maybe... But how does it stay fixed in the frame? Wouldn't it move while pedaling?

What is the value/ your attachment to the frame?  At some point it could become more expensive to repair than replace the frame, especially is you seem to have ability to do the work to move components to a new frame yourself.  Problem is that cost does not change, best to decide early if that is an option or if recovery of this frame is the path you want to go down.
There is a limited range of 73mm threadless BB shells available - e.g. (not a recommendation) https://www.modernbike.com/sunlite-sl55-73x111-square-taper-jis-bottom-bracket. This would probably be the cheapest and easiest solution, but I would be ordering a spare (or two) as the range is limited.
Other options if you cannot get a 73mm shipped or want a better solution - there is probably room to reduce the shell width to 68mm, giving the option of a 68mm threadless shell. A better option might be to ream the shell and cut Italian threads (36mmx24 TPI vs 1.37″x24 TPI, approximately 34.8mm diameter). Italian thread bottom brackets and cartridges are abundantly available. Both these options would best be done by someone who really knows what they are doing, either a very well-equipped bike shop or an engineering shop (or a bike shop working with an engineering shop).

Do you see any cross threading inside the shell? If my assumption is right, source of the problem is loosing the beginning of the threads. Tapping or re-threading is not an option in this case, no?

The look like they have been cross threaded. Two bike shops have had a crack at repairing and failed.  IMHO, Chances of a successful third attempt are limited (unless they are both exceptionally incompetent).
